# 2 column grid with canvas

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5-canvas

I'm just trying to make a 2 column grid based off an object. I want to put the text in the rectangles eventually. I will show you what I came up with. The main problem is that the recs y positions in the second column are not evenly spaced.
The margins don't look right.

```js
$(function(){

 var questions = {
     question1 : ["This is a question for statement 1 This is a question for statement 1", 7],
     question2 : ["This is a question for statement 2 This is a question for statement 2", 3],
     question3 : ["This is a question for statement 3 This is a question for statement 3", 8],
     question4 : ["This is a question for statement 4 This is a question for statement 4", 8],
     question5 : ["This is a question for statement 5 This is a question for statement 5", 8],
     question6 : ["This is a question for statement 6 This is a question for statement 6", 8],
     question7 : ["This is a question for statement 7 This is a question for statement 7", 8],
     question8 : ["This is a question for statement 8 This is a question for statement 8", 8]
    
    }
    var canvas = $("canvas")[0];
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
 
 var count0 = 0;
 var count1 = 1;
    for(var question in questions){
     var i = Object.keys(questions).indexOf(question);
     var a = i - 1;
     
     ctx.fillStyle = "green";
     if( i % 2 == 0 && i  == 0){
      ctx.fillRect(0, (i * 1) * 200, 200, 200)
     }else if(i % 2 == 0 && i  !== 0){
      count0++
     // console.log("count", count0)
      ctx.fillRect(0, (i * 1) * 210 - (200 *count0), 200, 200)
     }else if(i % 2 == 1 && i  == 1){
      ctx.fillRect(210, 0 * 200, 200, 200)
     }

     else if(i % 2 == 1 && i  !== 1){
      count1++
     // console.log("count", count1)
      ctx.fillRect(210, (i * 1) * 207 - (200 *count1), 200, 200)
      // ctx.fillRect(210, ())
     }
       
       
 }


  })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<canvas id "myCanvas" width = "700px" height = "1000px"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have the patience to figure out what exactly is going wrong with your code (although I would guess that multiplying by 210 in one column and 207 in the other is a big part of the problem), because it seems to me that you can get the desired result with much simpler code:

```js
$(function() {
  var questions = {
    question1: ["This is a question for statement 1 This is a question for statement 1", 7],
    question2: ["This is a question for statement 2 This is a question for statement 2", 3],
    question3: ["This is a question for statement 3 This is a question for statement 3", 8],
    question4: ["This is a question for statement 4 This is a question for statement 4", 8],
    question5: ["This is a question for statement 5 This is a question for statement 5", 8],
    question6: ["This is a question for statement 6 This is a question for statement 6", 8],
    question7: ["This is a question for statement 7 This is a question for statement 7", 8],
    question8: ["This is a question for statement 8 This is a question for statement 8", 8]
  }
  var canvas = $("canvas")[0];
  var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  ctx.font = "20px serif";
  
  Object.keys(questions).forEach(function(question, i) {
    var offset = i % 2;
    ctx.fillStyle = "green";
    ctx.fillRect(210 * offset, (i - offset) / 2 * 210, 200, 200);
    // next two lines optional:
    ctx.fillStyle = "white";
    ctx.fillText(question, 210 * offset + 30, (i - offset) / 2 * 210 + 60);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<canvas id "myCanvas" width="700px" height="1000px"></canvas>
```

Comment: That's a  brilliant solution. I hope to be as good as you one day.